# repeat div section in the length of list (Ionic)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a custom JavaScript file with some function in it. All the functions work perfectly fine.

One of the functions returns a list modules. I would like to repeat in my template the div section as many times is the length of my list.

This is my ionic template file:

```
<ion-view title="My Marks" id="page7">
<ion-content ng-controller="MyMarks" padding="true" class="has-header">

    <div ng-repeat="module in getCourseModules">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">{{module}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-50">Module Mark</div>
            <div class="col col-50">{{GenerateRandomMarks[i]}}</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And this is my controller inside my app.js:

```
app.controller('MyMarks', function ($scope){

$scope.courseNum = GenerateRandomNumber(0, 9);

$scope.getCourseName = getCourseName(courseNum);//Returns just Text

$scope.getCourseModules = getCourseModules(courseNum); //Returns the list
$scope.GenerateRandomMarks = GenerateRandomMarks(); //Returns a list of numbers
  });
```

How can I repeat the segment of code I need? and in that segment of code, each time is repeated it should display different element of the list {{getCourseModules[i]}}.

I solved the most of it. But I cant figure out the repeat part. If I manually copy/and paste the code it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="model in getCourseModules">{{model}}</div>

<div ng-repeat="model in getCourseModules">{{someAnotherArray[$index]}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @NechiK. I have updated my code in the 1st question. For getCourseModules is working fantastic. I have also another array in that segment of code which is the mark. The mark is returned in a list from a function. In order to use them I have to call them like {{Mark[x]}}.
model is not a number so I cant use that as my counter. How you recommend me to solve that?

Comment: You mean you need to know which index has each repeated element ? Or what ?

Comment: I need an index variable so I can list the marks which are located in the GenerateRandomMarks. Each time the div is repeated the GenerateRandomMarks[X] list should move to the next element of the array.

Comment: You can use $index inside repeated elements.
I edited my answer with example.

Comment: That's just brilliant NechiK ! Your answer will be marked as accepted. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: Welcome! But I have an advice for you. Read the documentation firstly. And learn base angular directives :)